# Control panel screen reloads when attempting to save changes on other pages

Tags: control-panel, saving

I usually just experience this at random intervals, but now all the time when attempting to save changes in the Freeform Pro plugin. I am pretty sure this is not just limited to the plugin as I have this problem on other templates and snippet pages. When I attempt to save changes, the screen redirects to the main control panel home without actually saving changes. This have been occuring infrequently and randomly since my original installation of v 2.5.